# iOS text-based adventure game / eBook: Should I use SpriteKit or UIKit?

Tags: ios, uikit, sprite-kit, game-engine, ios8

I want to create a **text-based iOS Game, resp. interactive ebook**. I will create chapters that get gradually unlocked after the player/reader has decided which path to take next. He/She cannot undo this decision. Music and little animations are involved as well.

From what I've learned so far, I think using **Storyboards** would make sense to stay organized with the different parts, but I am insecure whether to use Apple's own game framework **SpriteKit** or standard **UIKit** since little pixel art animations and music will be involved? Would it even make sense to mix them?

**What would you use? Thanks a lot in advance!**

Answer (score 2):

it depends on but basically it should be totally fine to go with UIKit. The great thing about it is you can integrate parts as you wish and can mix it as well. So in case that you need some more fancy effects you can move over and embeeded an view based on Spritekit but you can handle simple animations and effects easily with CoreGraphics/ CoreAnimation which are also part of UIKit

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Graphics_iPhone/index.html

best regards
Schreda

Comment: Thanks, Schreda! Any other opinions on this? Please let me know!